# \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} lowercase?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, capitalization

I am using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` to, for example, give my different bibliographies separate chapterheadings as well as have a short and a long table of contents.

However, using this command `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhalts\"ubersicht}`, the `\chaptertitle` is printed as desired, but the headertitle in the `ToC` is printed in uppercases, i.e. `INHALTSÜBERSICHT`, as can be seen here:

[image]

This, however, only happens when I use the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhalts\"ubersicht}` command, in all other cases it is as it should be, i.e. normal/lowercase except for the initial letter. What is the command to force `\addcontentsline` to do the same? How can I redefine it?

I am using the SV Mono Class 5.5 by Springer: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-springer-monographs-slash-textbooks/jkmjvjrkqrpb

As a MWE:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex  
\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhalts\"ubersicht} 
\shorttableofcontents{Inhalts\"ubersicht}{0} 
\cleardoublepage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage 
\include{Contents/acronym} 

\mainmatter
\chapter{Einleitung}
\chapter{Einleitung2}
\chapter{Einleitung3}
\chapter{Einleitung4}
\chapter{Einleitung99}
\chapter{Einleitung5}
\chapter{Einleitung6}
\chapter{Einleitung7}
\chapter{Einleitung8}
\chapter{Einleitung9}
\chapter{Einleitung10}
\chapter{Einleitung11}
\chapter{Einleitung12}
\chapter{Einleitung13}
\chapter{Einleitung14}
\chapter{Einleitung15}
\chapter{Einleitung16}
\chapter{Einleitung17}
\chapter{Einleitung18}
\chapter{Einleitung19}

\end{document}
```

Using the class, applied to my MWE, this is the output: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tdqjnpttdkkf

Comment: Clearly, it should be `Inhaltsübersicht` anyway, but by default, the content is not made uppercase. So this is something which your 'modified template' is to blame of

Comment: And the question is also: Why do you do use `\addcontentsline` at all if it is a `\chapter`? Or are you using `\chapter*`?

Comment: I am using \chapter* . The Umlauts do work as well. 
Is there any command such as redefine to "force" it lowercase?

Comment: Without seeing a real line of code: Only guess - work, sorry

Comment: Added the class im using and a MWE.

Comment: I've a different definition of a MWE: It compiles out of the box, but your 'MWE' doesn't :-( -- After kicking out some quirk it compiles however and it shows 'Inhaltsübersicht'

Comment: Yep, you are right. I didn't think I would be able to create a MWE, since I'm new to latex, but this one works for me, using the overleaf template and copy+pasting my MWE. Mind giving it a try? Many thanks already!

Comment: I wrote: I had to comment the many `\include` statements out, trying to write to directories I don't have. As I said: I can't reproduce your issue! Apparently you're talking about the page header and not about the ToC entry itself

Comment: Strange. It works for me now, using the template link I provided for overleaf - obviously the MWE wont work out of the box, as i suspect the template is lacking here and needs to be modified.

Comment: Check with Springer before you make any changes to the template.

Comment: I did - Also, I need to. Anyway, any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to `shorttoc` that seizes the initiative and applies `\uppercase` to the title.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex  

% patch \shorttableofcontents    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\shorttableofcontents}
  {\uppercase{#1}}
  {#1}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\shorttableofcontents}
  {\uppercase{#1}}
  {#1}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\shorttableofcontents}
  {\uppercase{#1}}
  {#1}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\shorttableofcontents}
  {\uppercase{#1}}
  {#1}
  {}{}
% end of patch

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhalts\"ubersicht} 
\shorttableofcontents{Inhalts\"ubersicht}{0} 
\cleardoublepage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage 
%\include{Contents/acronym} % don't have it

\mainmatter
\chapter{Einleitung}
\chapter{Einleitung2}
\chapter{Einleitung3}
\chapter{Einleitung4}
\chapter{Einleitung99}
\chapter{Einleitung5}
\chapter{Einleitung6}
\chapter{Einleitung7}
\chapter{Einleitung8}
\chapter{Einleitung9}
\chapter{Einleitung10}
\chapter{Einleitung11}
\chapter{Einleitung12}
\chapter{Einleitung13}
\chapter{Einleitung14}
\chapter{Einleitung15}
\chapter{Einleitung16}
\chapter{Einleitung17}
\chapter{Einleitung18}
\chapter{Einleitung19}

\end{document}
```

Four patches are needed for removing each `\uppercase`.

A single patch can be done with

```
% patch \shorttableofcontents
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\shorttableofcontents}
  {\uppercase{#1}}
  {#1}
  {}{}
\makeatother
% end of patch
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! works so far!
just for my understanding, why four patches?
also, the same happens to me with headers created by
    \printbibliography[title={Literatur}
at the end of my document. how would i apply the patch there?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh With `\patchcmd` you only modify *one* appearance of `\uppercase{#1}` into `#1`, but there are four of them. The `regexpatch` specific command `\xpatchcmd*` (note the `*`) does all the replacements in one step.

Comment: only the four patches-version works, the \xpatchcmd* does not work in my document.

Comment: @kuuhkuuh You need a fully updated TeX distribution, I guess.

Comment: anyway, it works well with a triple (?!) patch. 
Any idea on how to do the same magic for
"\printbibliography[title={Literatur}, filter=literatur, heading=bibintoc]" ? "Literatur" is uppercase in the header.

Comment: @kuuhkuuh The triple patch leaves an `\uppercase` hanging around: you'd see it if the short toc is three pages long. For the other problem I think a different question should be opened.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I opened another question for the other problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314146/biblatex-change-printbibliographytitle-header-output-from-uppercase-to-lo

Answer (score 3):

This is as a result of [`shorttoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc), which issues `\uppercase` for the header marks. You can change this by using

[image]

```
\usepackage{shorttoc,regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\shorttableofcontents}{\uppercase}{}{}{}% Remove all \uppercase
\makeatother
```