# Biblatex: Change \printbibliography[title={}] header output from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: biblatex, biber, capitalization

I am using the `\printbibliography[title={Legal Documents}]` command of `biblatex` with a `biber` backend in order to created several subchapters within my bibliography chapters. However, the output header/headertitle of the corresponding page is printed in uppercases, i.e. LEGAL DOCUMENTS, as can be seen here (picture from my MWE):

[image]

I am using the [SV Mono Class 5.5 by Springer](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-springer-monographs-slash-textbooks/jkmjvjrkqrpb).

I presume the problem is either due to the template or due to the standard settings of `biblatex`/`biber`. What is the command to force `\printbibliography` to give the output in lowercase letters? How can I redefine it?

Working example follows; it is not as minimum as I wish for it to be, since I have to show you guys the second page of the bibliography and therefore created a bunch of dummy bibliography entries, as can be seen below.

A Working Example:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex  
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter
\chapter{Einleitung}

Test Test \autocite[2]{ex1} Test \autocite[2]{ex2} Test \autocite[2]{ex3} Test \autocite[2]{ex4} Test \autocite[2]{ex5} Test \autocite[2]{ex6} Test \autocite[2]{ex7} Test \autocite[2]{ex8} Test \autocite[2]{ex9} Test \autocite[2]{ex10} Test \autocite[2]{ex11} Test \autocite[2]{ex12} Test \autocite[2]{ex13} Test \autocite[2]{ex14}  Test \autocite[2]{ex15}  Test \autocite[2]{ex16}  Test \autocite[2]{ex17}  Test \autocite[2]{ex18}  Test \autocite[2]{ex19}  Test \autocite[2]{ex20}  Test \autocite[2]{ex21}  Test \autocite[2]{ex22}  Test \autocite[2]{ex23}  Test \autocite[2]{ex24}  Test \autocite[2]{ex25}  Test \autocite[2]{ex26}  Test \autocite[2]{ex27}  Test \autocite[2]{ex28}  Test \autocite[2]{ex29}  Test \autocite[2]{ex30} Test \autocite[2]{ex31} Test \autocite[2]{ex32} Test \autocite[2]{ex33} Test \autocite[2]{ex34} Test \autocite[2]{ex35} Test \autocite[2]{ex36} Test \autocite[2]{ex37} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\chaptermark{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[title={Legal Documents}]

\end{document}
```

The corresponding lit.bib:

```
@misc{ex1,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex2,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex3,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex4,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex5,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex6,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex7,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex8,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex9,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex10,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex11,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex12,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex13,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex14,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex15,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex16,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex17,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex18,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex19,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex20,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex21,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex22,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex23,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex24,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex25,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex26,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex27,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex28,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex29,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex30,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex31,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex32,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex33,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex34,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex35,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex36,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex37,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
@misc{ex38,
    Author = {{Author}},
    Howpublished = {Name},
    Year = {1981}}
```

You can jump to my MWE using this link: https://www.overleaf.com/5445314wzbgkh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\chaptermark{Bibliography}

\defbibheading{bibliographysection}{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\printbibliography[heading=bibliographysection,title={Legal Documents}]
```

The standard heading has `\MakeUppercase`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works for me so far.  However, I used the "heading=bibintoc" command in order for the entry to show in my TOC. Any suggestion on how to also include this in your code, i.e. to get the best of both worlds ;) ?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh My impression, reading your code, is that you have several bibliography sections. So it would be wrong hard coding the `\chapter*` business in the heading for a particular bibliography section.

Comment: I use a \addcontentsline, \chapter* and \chaptermark to create a "Bibliography" chapter, which has several different bibliography sections, that I would like to also show up in my TOC. So far, my solution for this was using heading=bibintoc, which worked well thus far.

Comment: @kuuhkuuh So you also want the sections in the TOC? See the edit

Comment: Awesome, works very well! You are my hero. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a `prenote` - arbitrary text - to be used just after the heading has been set:

[image]

```
\defbibnote{legaldoc}{\markboth{Legal Documents}{Legal Documents}}
\printbibliography[title=Legal Documents,prenote=legaldoc]
```

The above `legaldoc` note overrides whatever other marks have been set.